# Suspend/Resume/Tombstone simulation in Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, resume, windows-phone-8-emulator, suspend, tombstoning

How can I simulate the suspend mode in the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator?
The **Suspending** event has to be fired.
Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24103734/2681948) shows how to susped the App in both Emulator/Device.

Answer (score 2):

Romasz's comment is correct for suspend/resume. You can do it from the Lifecycle events dropdown while the app is running via Visual Studio as shown here: [Suspending event not raising using WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103101/suspending-event-not-raising-on-windows-phone-8-1-using-winrt/24103734#24103734)

For tombstoning there is supposed to be a setting in the project's properties and debug tab which enables tombstone on suspend but I am unable to find it in Visual Studio 2013. Hence me stumbling across this post. Will follow up if I find more. Here is what it is supposed to look like: http://developerpublish.com/how-to-enable-windows-phone-application-tombstone-in-emulator-when-debugging/