# Handling MediaCapture Suspend/Resume Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to properly dispose the `MediaCapture` object when the user presses on the phone's Start or Back button. I presently handle the Back pressed event through the `HardwareButtons.BackPressed` event handler and dispose the `MediaCapture` object. When I re-enter the app however, the Resuming event is never called and I cannot recreate the `MediaCapture` object. I tried subscribing to `Application.Current.Resuming` for this but it is not called. I know my handler is functioning as when I play with the Lifecycle events in debug, the appropriate handlers are called. I also tried handling the `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigationLoadState` but these do not get called either when the app is "*resumed*" from holding the Back button from the start menu and then tapping on my app.

I also need to know which event is called when a user presses the Start button from within the app. Both the `OnSuspending` and `OnNavigationSaveState` are not called during this event. Is there something similar to `HardwareButtons.BackPressed` for the Start button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suspending event not raising on Windows Phone 8.1 using WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103101/suspending-event-not-raising-on-windows-phone-8-1-using-winrt)

Answer (score 1):

After looking at this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249159/detecting-deactivation-and-app-close-in-windows-phone-8-1-xaml), I realized that the reason I was not seeing the Suspend / Resume event being triggered was because I was running the app in Debug mode. Normally, the Suspend event is fired when the user navigates away from the app. Resume is also called if you load the app from the app list.