# Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight hide Navigation Bar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I had windows phone 8.0 project retargeted it 8.1, but there's not ApplicationView class, which I need.

Basically I just need this:

> Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible);

I'd like to use this too:

> Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SuppressSystemOverlays = true;

to hide navigation bar when app starts. However it's not accessible from silverlight and it's also not default value (true). 
And this case is even more amusing. As you will swipe to show navigation bar when it's hidden (tested on blank wp 8.1 app and many top games from store) there's no way to hide it anymore.

Comment: you can find some useful info about re-targeting to WP8.1 from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24627649/815938).

Comment: and you don't want to occupy status bar and app bar by setting `ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible`, right? but doesn't it have the same effect if you do nothing?

Comment: That's right I don't want navigation bar to cover my cocos2d-x game. Seems like it's a lot more complex problem.

Comment: OK, I understand why you need WP8.1, unfortunately re-targeting can't be done by a simple click, you have to port it manually and could have compile issues, said the link.

Comment: The navigation bar shouldn't cover your game - `UseVisible` is the default value (but not accessible to Silverlight apps since there is no `ApplicationView`).

Comment: @Peter Torr: can you look at my edited question?

Comment: My understanding is that the navigation bar is on by default and until the user goes into the Settings apps are not able to hide it. Once an app hides it, there should be a gesture to re-show it (or if you lock / unlock the navigation bar should return). Basically "most people" will always have the navigation bar visible. Sadly you need specific phones to test this feature and I don't have such a phone.