# When App Loses Focus, Do This

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, live-tile, lost-focus, startmenu

I have a method that I need to run when my app loses focus.  Specifically, I need to update my live tile every time the user goes to the start menu.  How can I trigger this method whenever the user either presses the back button or the start menu button?

I thought if I put it in the `OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)` method in `App.xaml.cs` that it would work, but it turns out this is not the case!!  The closes I have found is when the app launches, but that doesn't really do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Suspending event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx) is the thing you are looking for:

> When the user moves an app to the background, the OS waits a few seconds to see whether the user immediately switches back to the app. If the user does not switch back, the OS suspends the app.

But this event is **not** being raised while [you are debugging and you send your app to background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24103101/2681948). Normally (without debuging) it should work fine. Remember only that you have limited time to perform actions in this event, also don't forget to obtain a deferral and release it:

```cs
private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
   var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
   // do your code here
   deferral.Complete();
}
```

Comment: are you following me? ;-)

Comment: @Evorlor No :), I'm just following some tags.