# Crash occurs while not debugging, and while Debugging App runs perfectly

Tags: debugging, crash, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Platform - Windows Phone 8.1

when i run my app normally (without debugging), app crashes on one specific point.
and When i start debugging the app to catch the exception, it runs perfect.
I've faced this issue on more than 1 scenario, so I'm not mentioning the code.

Does anybody faced same situation before on WP8.1 ?

PS - I've tried debugging the app in Debug Mode as well as Release Mode.

Comment: Can you post some code? Describe a sitaution when it crashes? Provide more info? One thing that comes to my mind is that you may have problems with supspending/resuming event - while debugging they are not fired.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suspending event not raising on Windows Phone 8.1 using WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103101/suspending-event-not-raising-on-windows-phone-8-1-using-winrt)