# OnNavigatedFrom in Window Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am moving from Windows Phone 8 to Windows Phone 8.1.

I Created a Windows Phone 8.1 Store Application, Hub App.

The application created the OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom methods

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs e )
    {
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo( e );
    }

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom( NavigationEventArgs e )
    {
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom( e );
    }
```

I put a breakpoint in the OnNavigatedFrom and tried to either close the application, or to leave the application and the breakpoint is not hit, i.e. the application doesn't reach the OnNavigatedFrom.

A Windows Phone 8 application is breaking on the OnNavigatedFrom. Is the mechanism is different with WP 8.1? if so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to occur, because you are running in *Debug* mode (VS attached). In this situation your program behaves little different in case Navigation/Suspend events, to test it properly you will have to invoke the [Suspending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending.aspx) event manually ([Lifecyce events dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103734/2681948)). In normal situation both events (*OnNavigatedFrom* and *Suspending*) will be called just after you leave the app.

To test it let's put something in *OnNavigatedFrom* (basing on *Hub App* from Windows Store templates):

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("OnNavigatedFrom");
    Hub.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

in this case, when you run the app without Visual Studio attached, when you return to the app the background should be red - which means that the event has been fired.

There is, in fact, one more huge (IMO) difference when moving to WP8.1 WinRT - *OnNavigatedTo* [won't be fired when you come back from suspension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx):

> Note  On Windows Phone, OnNavigatedFrom() is called when the app is suspended. OnNavigatedTo() is not called when the app is resumed.

it's called only when you navigate.

Some more references: [Navigating between pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx), [Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx), [Launching, resuming, and multitasking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh770837.aspx) and [Guidelines for app suspend and resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will follow the links you provided. 