# WindowsPhone 8.1 App Crashes

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

i can't figure out, why my App crashes or closes (it just quits, no break in debug-mode)

i try to navigate to another view, there are two possibilities, one works, the second causes the Crash:

```
        private void Nachricht_EventClickTelMac_Mac(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //MenuFlyoutItem mfi = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
        //GeräteAuslesenNavigationParameter p = new GeräteAuslesenNavigationParameter();
        //p.MacAdressen = new List<string>();
        //p.AuftragId = _viewmodel.Auftrag.auftrag_id;
        //p.KundenNummer="";
        //p.MacAdressen.Add((string)mfi.CommandParameter);
        //mfi = null;
        //sender = null;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(GeräteAuslesen), null);
    }
    private void KundenwerteAuslesen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //GeräteAuslesenNavigationParameter p = new GeräteAuslesenNavigationParameter();
        //p.KundenNummer = _viewmodel.Auftrag.kunden_nr.ToString();
        //p.AuftragId = _viewmodel.Auftrag.auftrag_id;
        //p.MacAdressen = new List<string>();
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(GeräteAuslesen), null);
    }
```

I've commented out all differences, so the only difference is the Sender

KundenwerteAuslesen works well, 
Nachricht_EventClickTelMac_Mac leads to the Crash ... you can see the elements of the desired view flying in for about half a second, then the app Closes

does anybody have a clue whats going on?

> Are the lines of code commented out when you observe the crash? and what event is calling those methods? (i.e. a button click?) –  erotavlas 3 mins ago

yea it is commented out, because i wanted to know if the Problem is in These lines, but it isn't

this is the method calling Nachricht_EventClickTelMac_Mac:

```
        private void Nachricht_EventClickTelMac(Hyperlink arg1, string arg2)
    {
        MenuFlyout fl = new MenuFlyout();

        MenuFlyoutItem mfi1 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
        mfi1.Text = "Telefonnummer Anrufen";
        mfi1.Click += Nachricht_EventClickTelMac_Tel;
        mfi1.CommandParameter = arg2;

        MenuFlyoutItem mfi2 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
        mfi2.Text = "Mac-Adresse auslesen";
        mfi2.Click += Nachricht_EventClickTelMac_Mac;
        mfi2.CommandParameter = arg2;

        fl.Items.Add(mfi1);
        fl.Items.Add(mfi2);
        fl.ShowAt(Frame);
    }
```

and this is the XAML calling KundenwerteAuslesen:

```
<AppBarButton x:Key="abb_equip_auslesen" Label="Kundenwerte auslesen" Click="KundenwerteAuslesen"/>
```

EDIT: App reaches Breakpoint at the end of the Contructor, at the end of NavigationHelper_LoadState and at the end of OnNavigatedTo

EDIT: i've changed the target-view to navigate to, but the pronlem still persists, so i assume, that the Problem occurs in the current view

Comment: [Try to debug Suspending events](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24103734/2681948).

Comment: i don't know, why i should suspend the app ... "Suspending event won't fire while you are Debugging" - i'm only in debug-mode ... Maybe i told it incorrectly, the app crashes while navigating from one Page to another

Comment: Are the lines of code commented out when you observe the crash? and what event is calling those methods? (i.e. a button click?)

Comment: i've edited the post, hope it helps helping me ;)

Comment: opposite order? do you think of the order of the menuFlyoutItems? Edit: changed the order of the MenuFlyoutItems, but as expected no effect

Comment: Can you try to obtain the exception?

Comment: i would if i could ... there is no exception ... at least no exception i can see ... no break, nothing, it is as if i would just Close the app normaly

Comment: https://ertayshashko.wordpress.com/2014/05/27/how-to-access-unhandled-exceptions-in-windows-phone-8-1-winrt-app/

Comment: i have included some code from here http://www.markermetro.com/2013/01/technical/handling-unhandled-exceptions-with-asyncawait-on-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8/ ans set brakepoints, but no breakpoint matches, Output says: Das Programm "[492] ....exe" wurde mit Code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation' beendet.

Comment: If it crash while debugging, then it is in fact less chance that it's caused by suspension. Were you have this code: `<AppBarButton x:Key="abb_equip_auslesen" ...` - is it some kind of Resource? You cannot have UI elements as a Resource - it can have only one parent, so once you try to set the second time, there is chance you will get exception.

Comment: the button works perfectly, but when coming from the menuflyoutitem, the app crashes. I guess that this has something to do with the generated menuflyout, because the methods are the same, except for the arguments. even the new view gets initialized, May be it is something with unloading the old page?

Comment: Hard to say, is it possible that you share a sample project?