# Windows Phone App crashes after Launcher.LaunchFileAsync when downloaded from store

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

I have a strange problem, if I deploy my app through visual studio as debug or release version all is working well. But if I publish it to the store and download it from there the app crashes after `Launcher.LaunchFileAsync` or `FileOpenPicker`.

When my app launches for example the default app for photos, the photo is loaded into the photo app and got displayed. After pushing the Hardwarebackbutton, the store installation goes back to the `windows phone home screen`, the visual studio deployed version goes back to the last screen of my app. The same issue is with the `FileOpenPicker`.

In a previous version of my app this works and I haven't changed the code around this. New in this version is the usage of Unity and Prism (in the previous I haven't used any container framework).

I tried to debug this with an store beta app and write all `UnhandledExceptions` to a file in `LocalStorage`, but it seems that there are no UnhandledException.

Does anyone had the same problems and have some hints or experiences to find out the problem? Is there any possibility to debug my app downloaded from the store?

Exception from the store:

```
"Frame    Bild                                                Funktion                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Offset        
0        Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 DirectUI::NavigationHistory::WritePageStackEntryToString                                                                                                                                                                                               0x000000f9    
1        Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 DirectUI::NavigationHistory::GetNavigationState                                                                                                                                                                                                        0x000000d7    
2        Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 DirectUI::Frame::GetNavigationStateImpl                                                                                                                                                                                                                0x0000002f    
3        Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 DirectUI::FrameGenerated::GetNavigationState                                                                                                                                                                                                           0x00000033    
4        WINDOWS.NI.WINMD                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0x00403a41    
5        Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.ni.DLL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0x0000c661    
6        Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.ni.DLL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0x0000d191    
7        Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.ni.DLL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0x0000e739    
8        Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.ni.DLL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0x0000f5df    
9        Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.ni.DLL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0x0000cc81    
10       Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.Phone.ni.DLL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0x00005ed3    
11       Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.Phone.ni.DLL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0x000063f3    
12       Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.Phone.ni.DLL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0x00005723    
13       WINDOWS.NI.WINMD                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0x004bacc5    
14       CoreClr.dll                                         COMToCLRDispatchHelper                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0x0000003d    
15       CoreClr.dll                                         GenericComCallStub                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0x00000019    
16       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 Microsoft::WRL::EventSource_Windows::UI::Xaml::ISuspendingEventHandler,Microsoft::WRL::InvokeModeOptions_-2_ _::DoInvoke__lambda_23bdf1386dc85166ec5d0f15e3e7ceef_ _                                                                                   0x00000047    
17       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 XAML::PLM::ASTAEventSource_Windows::UI::Xaml::ISuspendingEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::ApplicationModel::ISuspendingEventArgs_::InvokeHandlers                                                                                                    0x0000000d    
18       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 XAML::PLM::PLMHandler::OnSuspending                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0x00000095    
19       twinapi.appcore.dll                                 Microsoft::WRL::InvokeTraits_-2_::InvokeDelegates__lambda_19fa2f90eeadc306808dc8b8c64b7666_,Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler_Windows::ApplicationModel::SuspendingEventArgs *_ _                                                                     0x00000057    
20       twinapi.appcore.dll                                 Microsoft::WRL::EventSource_Windows::Foundation::IEventHandler_Windows::ApplicationModel::SuspendingEventArgs *_,Microsoft::WRL::InvokeModeOptions_-2_ _::DoInvoke__lambda_19fa2f90eeadc306808dc8b8c64b7666_ _                                         0x0000004d    
21       twinapi.appcore.dll                                 Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::SuspendResume                                                                                                                                                                                    0x000000b3    
22       twinapi.appcore.dll                                 _lambda_806d9f75e467416c61267ff2e6219463_::operator                                                                                                                                                                                                    0x00000055    
23       twinapi.appcore.dll                                 Microsoft::WRL::Details::InvokeHelper_Microsoft::WRL::Implements_Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags_2_,Windows::UI::Core::IDispatchedHandler,Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Details::Nil,Microsoft::WRL::Detai    0x0000000f    
24       windows.ui.dll                                      Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessInvokeItem                                                                                                                                                                                                      0x000001b3    
25       windows.ui.dll                                      Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages                                                                                                                                                                                                 0x000001dd    
26       windows.ui.dll                                      Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents                                                                                                                                                                                                          0x00000063    
27       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop                                                                                                                                                                                                               0x0000003b    
28       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 CJupiterControl::RunMessageLoop                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0x0000001b    
29       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0x00000027    
30       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll                                 DirectUI::FrameworkView::Run                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0x0000000f    
31       twinapi.appcore.dll                                 Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run                                                                                                                                                                                              0x00000027    
32       twinapi.appcore.dll                                 _lambda_57350c7fa2f68b1d43d8bfac2a0781a8_::operator                                                                                                                                                                                                    0x000000c7    
33       shcore.dll                                          _WrapperThreadProc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0x00000149    
34       ntdll.dll                                           RtlUserThreadStart                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0x00000017"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you failed to use LaunchFileAsync/FileOpenPicker correctly. [Follow this guide carefully](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn614994).

Unless debugging, OS terminates your process just after you've called the picker (especially on low-memory devices with 512MB RAM). It's up to your application to save its state, and when reactivated restore the state and take user to the exact place in your app where she was.

[Also, here’s how you can debug the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103734/126995).

Comment: Indeed, the Async methods don't work under Windows Phone 8.1, PickSingleFileAndContinue(); and PickSaveFileAndContinue(); are for example to be used along with Continue data - I have an example using these which works fine https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/04/13/windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-universal-application-text-editor/