# Onsuspend event is not fired in windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am working in windows 10 app. I am really confused when windows 10 app suspend and resume events are fired. I have below event in App.cs page, however, this event never fires.

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
   var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
   //TODO: Save application state and stop any background           
 ApplicationSettingsHelper.SaveSettingsValue(ApplicationSettingsConstants.AppState, (short)AppState.Suspended);
   ApplicationDataSource.saveRecent(Recent);
   deferral.Complete();
}
```

I have also tried to add onsuspend event in MainPage load event using below code, but this is also never fired.

```
Application.Current.Suspending += Current_Suspending;
```

when does the event Onsuspend is fired and what is the difference between the two above method?

Thanks!

Comment: Debugging a suspended app isn't a lot of fun.  So you have to invoke it yourself.  Well hidden btw, right-click the VS toolbar and click "Debug Location".  You now get a "Lifecycle events" dropdown, pick "Suspend".

Answer (score 2):

That's because OnSuspended will not raise if you are normal debugging.
Please look at answer to this question [Suspending event not raising using WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103101/suspending-event-not-raising-on-windows-phone-8-1-using-winrt)