# OnSleep and OnResume not called

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

In my UWP and Windows Phone 8.1 projects only OnStart is called. When I exit the app via the back button or home button, OnSleep is not called. If I open the app OnResume is not called.

It looks like the app never goes in the Deactivated state.

I tried it with Android and it is working fine. Why are these methods not called in both Windows projects?

Comment: Which version of `Xamarin.Forms` are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.1.0.6529 which is the latest stable release.

Comment: I know there were issues related to this exact problem under 2.0.x, you might want to try the prerelease version, 2.2.0.5-pre2, in a sample project to see if these events are being called. In regarding to the older version, see https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52524/windows-8-1-windows-phone-8-1-windows-10-related-issues

Comment: I have tried the latest prelease, but no luck. Might [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103101/suspending-event-not-raising-using-winrt) be related?

Comment: Have you tried setting the LifeCycle to suspend and then back to resume via the `LifeCycle Events` in VS? Does the `OnResume` event in Forms get called then?

Comment: Yes, they do get called that way.

Comment: Great, than that bug was fixed...

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug in Xamarin.Forms 2.0: [OnStart / OnResume are not called on WP8.1](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36730) which according to bugzilla was fixed in 2.1.0-pre1 version. If this is still not working for you, you should reopen the issue and attach your project which reproduces the issue.

As a workaround you can try using application lifecycle event in windows phone project: [App lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) but this is obviously platform specific solution.