# How to debug this Windows 10 phone crash when sharing to Twitter?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, share-button

Github project is at https://github.com/GarthSmith/WindowsTwitterShareTestApp2016 with an appxbundle available [here](https://github.com/GarthSmith/WindowsTwitterShareTestApp2016/releases).

This app crashes on my Lumia 929 phone with Windows 10. Clicking the share button runs `DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI()`. Waiting on the Twitter login screen will then crash the app.

It does not crash if I have a debugger attached. It only crashes on my ARM phone with no debugger attached.

- How do I debug this crash?
- How can I capture this crash for reporting?

Comment: I guess that this may be a [problem in suspending event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24103734/2681948) - to debug it use lifecycle tab.

Comment: I tested your project in Lumia 950, OS Build:10586.218 Version:1511 and it works well. I don't have a Lumia 929 phone, but you may try to test your project in other devices to see if it still has the same problem.

Comment: @Romasz thank you for pointing this out! I did not know about this. Unfortunately, firing the suspending event did not seem to cause the crash.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Thank you for checking this. I did a factory reset of my Lumia 929, built 10.0.10586.218, Version 1511, and it still is crashing. Testing on another Lumia 929 also crashed. I am getting some more devices tonight to test some more.

If the app says "No clicks yet" after logging into Twitter, that means the app has crashed and been restarted by the OS. I will update the project to make it more obvious.

Comment: I tested it on my Lumia 1320 with 10586.242 (Release Preview Ring) and after clickon on share and selecting Twitter, the Twitter App starts fine. I see no crash.

Comment: I don't think this is a crash anymore, but my misunderstanding. From the [documentation on the Application.Suspending event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242341): "The Suspending event is the only indication your app will receive prior to termination (if it happens). Because of this, you should store enough session state (such as the current article being read or the current movie playback position) to recreate the exact same experience during activation."